# for loop in train(caret) to select different predictors in a lm model

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, lm

I'm just a beginner, so  i hope you can help with a problem due the KNN model (via train in caret) in R.

I tried this:

```
models.list = as.list(vector(length = ncol(FIFA21_db)))
for(i in 1:ncol(mtcars)) {
  models.list[[i]] <- train(x = mtcars[,i], y = mtcars[,1], method = "lm")
}
```

This cause the  error " Please use column names for `x`": Do you know how i can use the column names instead of observations in a for loop? My goal is to use different variables for a lm regression.

Comment: Reading the documentation (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/4.47/topics/train) it looks like x has to be a dataframe. I would double check what you are sending it is a dataframe.

Comment: The examples section might be helpful.. I think part of it might be because you are using a lm model but I am not 100% sure, normal for lm, you do something like, train(y~x, data=mtcars, method="lm")